# Change width of DiV element using range slider and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, addeventlistener

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Range Slider Width</title>
<script src="slajder.js"></script>
<style>
  #ekran {
      width: 80px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: pink;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='range' min="1" max="400" value="150">
    <div id='ekran'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Without ID on input range slider with only id on DIV element i needed to write JS code so when i move slider acording to a value of a slider width of that DIV element with ID ='ekran' is chaning too. (with a slider of course). Im not sure if CSS is correct but i had something like this on exam. Please help guys. I beginer in JS. Learning it still and i have a looooot more to learn.

PS: if value of range slider is '30' width of that div will be 30px. thats all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the value of the slider with from the `input` event from the slider like this

```
e.target.value
```

and set that to the width of the div

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('[type=range]')
let div = document.querySelector('#ekran')

slider.addEventListener('input', e => {
  div.style.width = e.target.value + 'px'
})
```

```css
#ekran {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<input type='range' min="1" max="400" value="80">
<div id='ekran'></div>
```

Comment: Btw something not working. I just tried. I added ; on every variable and after function.... Dunno whats going on.

Comment: Hi, I was looking for an example like this. But I need help with it. 
I have to change the width & height but I have to use Jquery instead of Javascript.